# Kotlin casting Int to Float

Tags: kotlin, casting

I'm trying to learn Kotlin, and I've just made a calculator program from console.
I have functions to sum, divide, etc. And when I try to cast integers to float, I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Float

The function is this:

```
fun divide(a: Int, b: Int): Float {
    return a as Float / b as Float;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To confirm other answers, and correct what seems to be a common misunderstanding in Kotlin, the way I like to phrase it is:

**A cast does not *convert* a value into another type; a cast promises the compiler that the value already *is* the new type.**

If you had an `Any` or `Number` reference that happened to point to a `Float` object:

```
val myNumber: Any = 6f
```

Then you could cast it to a Float:

```
myNumber as Float
```

But that only works because the object already *is* a `Float`; we just have to tell the compiler.  That wouldn't work for another numeric type; the following would give a `ClassCastException`:

```
myNumber as Double
```

To *convert* the number, you don't use a cast; you **use one of the conversion functions**, e.g.:

```
myNumber.toDouble()
```

Some of the confusion may come because languages such as C and Java have been fairly lax about numeric types, and perform silent conversions in many cases.  That can be quite convenient; but it can also lead to subtle bugs.  For most developers, low-level bit-twiddling and calculation is less important than it was 40 or even 20 years ago, and so Kotlin moves some of the numeric special cases into the standard library, and requires explicit conversions, bringing extra safety.

Comment: And in some cases the compiler can definitively tell when a cast will fail, hence the compile error rather than a ClassCastException at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

The exception's stacktrace pretty much explained why the cast can never succeed:

> java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Float

Neither of the classes `java.lang.Integer` and `java.lang.Float` is extending the other so you can't cast `java.lang.Integer` to `java.lang.Float` (or vice versa) with `as`.

You should use `.toFloat()`.

```kotlin
fun divide(a: Int, b: Int): Float {
    return a.toFloat() / b
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As it states, an Int cannot be cast to a Float. However both `kotlin.Int` and `kotlin.Float` inherit `kotlin.Number` which defines `abstract fun toFloat(): Float`. This is what you will need in this scenario.

```
fun divide(a:Int, b:Int): Float {
  return a.toFloat() / b.toFloat()
}
```

Please refer to https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/to-float.html for more information.

Answer (score -1):

another way

```
fun divide(a: Int, b: Int) = a.div(b).toFloat()
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.