# Typecasting from Double to Float results in ClassCastException

Tags: kotlin

**Code:-**

```
val num = 12.12
val num2: Float = num.toFloat() // Works
val num3: Float = num as Float // Exception
```

**Exception:-**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Double cannot be cast to class java.lang.Float (java.lang.Double and java.lang.Float are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

Can anyone tell me why `num.toFloat()` works just fine but `num as Float` gives an error? Aren't both these different syntaxes supposed to do the same thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they're not doing the same thing.

`.toXxx()` methods *convert* a value from one type to another.  This can be a distantly-related type (e.g. `List` to `String`), or a closely-related type (e.g. `Int` to `Float`), but in all cases they're different types, and have different values.

`as`, however, is a *cast*.  **A cast doesn't convert a value to the required type; a cast promises the compiler that the value is *already* of the required type.**  If it's not, you get an error, as you've discovered.

Languages such as C and Java are fairly lax about numeric types, and will automatically convert between them in many circumstances (‘numeric promotion’), which may be why you're confusing the two.  That can be quite convenient; but it can also lead to subtle bugs.  So Kotlin does far fewer, bringing extra safety (which is one of the themes of the language).

(This confusion seems to be quite common; see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61129343/kotlin-casting-int-to-float/61131112) from only 4 days ago.)

Comment: If it is already known what type of variable it is at the compile time itself then what is the use of  the `as` cast anyway?

Comment: @ParagKadam Sometimes you know something the compiler doesn't.  (Though not quite as often as people think, IME...) In those cases, where you can be certain a cast won't fail, then it can be useful.  (However, Kotlin's safe-cast `as?` operator, which makes it easier to handle the ‘impossible’, is often a better alternative.)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
val doubleVal: Double = 14.15
val castedFloatValue: Float = "${doubleVal}".toFloat()
```